# GCP & Azure: AADSTS700016:You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Error When just using GCP Custom Domain on Azure AD Login

Tags: node.js, azure, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory

I have deployed Node JS App on Google App Engine successfully however after deployment and login this url https://mydomain-473829.uc.r.appspot.com works fine and logins in, but when use I custom subdomain like https://api.mydomain.com?

It gives me this error on login

AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'guid' was not found in the directory 'directory-id'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Digging Deeper:

- Is this the error of GCP or Microsoft side?
- Why does one URL work fine and other not reach the right tenant, they are the same endpoint right from going through this setup: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains
- Does another tenant need provision and allow access to my multi-tenant app? Right now its only single tenant app?
- Is there any code changes needed, if so I can update this question if it is needed?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'guid' was not found in the directory 'directory-id'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

[image]

The error usually occurs if you are passing wrong **`client_id`** in the authorization/authentication request.

Make sure to pass the **`client_id`** of the Azure AD Application in the request.

[image]

- Also make sure that you are passing correct **`Tenant_ID`** of the Azure AD Application.
- Check whether the required permissions are granted for the Application.

For ***sample***, I used the below authorize endpoint by passing the correct **`client_id`**  like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

***The user signed in successfully like below:***

[image]

[image]

- The error is in the Microsoft Azure Side. Make sure to pass the correct values.

**Note** that: If you want your application to be accessed by other tenant users, then configure the Azure AD Application as **`Multi-Tenant`** like below:

[image]

If you configure the Application as **`Multi-Tenant`** then you must make use of organizations endpoint:

Authorize Endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Token Endpoint:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: Thanks. Ok I doubled checked my client ID and its the same for both, but still this url https://mydomain-473829.uc.r.appspot.com works fine and logins in as you displayed, but when use a gcp custom subdomain like https://api.mydomain.com it gives that error. Not sure why, any ideas, would help